# Problem with Closing Sockets. Program Halts

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am having some trouble with [this code](http://pastebin.com/mbd132a7). The problem is when i Request the Server to send me some data and the client just Disconnects when the server tries to send me data, the application Exists.

Here's the lines I think cause the problem

```
int SendBinary(int *byte, int length)
{
    int bytes_sent;

    bytes_sent = send(connecting_socket, byte, length, 0);

    return bytes_sent;


    return 0;
}

void SendFile(FILE *fp, int file_size)
{
    int current_char = 0;

    do{
        current_char = fgetc(fp);

        if ( current_char == EOF )
            break;

        SendBinary(&current_char, sizeof(char));
    }
    while(current_char != EOF);

}
```

Any ideas what i should do to prevent this? Revise the whole source for complements to this snippet.

Comment: There isn't a whole lot of information to go on here.

How is the server exiting? If it's segfault, have you used a debugger to determine where the fault occurs?

Comment: No it's not segfault , just terminates without any messages.

Comment: You should never use sizeof (char). It is defined as 1, so it only adds confusion to the code.

Also, you're code is likely broken, since it reads a char into an int, then passes a pointer to that int to a function (send()) expecting a pointer to bytes.

Comment: send expects a void*. And sizeof(char) is system dependant. sure in this case its Unix, where it's 1. BUT it's good practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps your application is receiving SIGPIPE during the write/send and not ignoring it? Try ignoring this signal or installing a do-nothing handler for it.

Comment: Like this? signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

Comment: Works like a charm. How would one Really handle SIGPIPE?

Comment: Almost every program ignores SIGPIPE.  You will know it happened when the write() or send() fails by properly checking the returned error codes.

Comment: A good way to detect errors and crashes related to stuff like this and more is to run strace on your program.  I can't count how many times strace has been a life saver for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure client didn't fail on receiving the data from server?

1. `telnet` to your server to see
   what it sends in response
2. Replace your server with
   `netcat` to make sure client is
   behaving correctly
3. Sniff the traffic between server and
   client using `tcpdump` or similar
   tool

Comment: The client is Chrome and IE, since it's a webserver. In the Chrome case it should behave good, but you never know with IE ;)